# Non-english characters are decoded incorrectly on Android with HtlmCleaner

Tags: java, android, encoding, html-parsing

I'm using `HtmlCleaner` to scrape a `ISO-8859-1` encoded web site in Android.

I've implemented this in an external `jar` file that I import into my Android app.

When I run the unit tests in Eclipse it handles Norwegian letters (`æ,ø,å`) correct (I can verify that in the debugger), but in the Android app these characters look like inverted question marks.

If I attach the debugger to my Android app I can see that these letters are not correct in the exact same places they were good when running unit test from Eclipse, so it's not a display/render/view issue in the Android app.

When I copy the text from the debuggers I get these results:

**Java Process (Unit Test)**:   «Blårek», «Benny»

**Android Process (In emulator)**:  «Bl�rek», «Benny»

I would expect these Strings to be equal, but notice how the "å" is replaed by the inverted question marks in Android.

I have tried running `htmlCleaner.getProperties().setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true)` without any luck. Also, I found no way of forcing UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoding in html cleaner, but I' not sure if that would have made a difference.

Here is the code i run:

```
HtmlCleaner htmlCleaner = new HtmlCleaner();

// connect to url and get root TagNode from HtmlCleaner
InputSteram is = new URL( url ).openConnection().getInputStream();
TagNode rootNode = htmlCleaner.clean( is );

// navigate through some TagNodes, getting the ContentNode 
ContentNode cn = rootNode... 

// This String contains the incorrectly decoded characters on Android. 
// Good in Oracle JVM though..
String value = cn.toString().trim();
```

Does anyone knows what could cause the decoding behavoir to be different on Android? I guess the main difference between the two environments is that the Android app uses Android's java.io stack while my unit tests use Sun/Oracle's stack.

Thanks,
Geir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HtmlCleaner` can't tell what encoding to use; you are passing only the body of the response in the `InputStream`, but the encoding is in the "content-type" header.

You can [set the character encoding](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/CleanerProperties.html#setCharset%28java.lang.String%29) on the properties of the `HtmlCleaner` to the correct encoding from the HTTP connection. But that would require you to parse the correct parameter from the content-type header. Alternatively, you can [pass a `URL` instance to `HtmlCleaner`](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/HtmlCleaner.html#clean%28java.net.URL%29) and let it manage the connection. Then, it will have access to all the information it needs to decode properly.